# RxAndroid & Retrofit Best approach for handling errors

Tags: android, retrofit, rx-android

I have some doubts about an approach I'm trying to implement on an Android App.

*The services of the app are able to send a http error code when an user has lost his session or it has expired.*

Since I'm new on RxAndroid I have doubts about how to implement a generic way to handle it with a Generic observable.

The server calls can be done in either a Presenter or a Manager class, and the idea is to notify the Activity.

would it  be a good approach to use Rx android like Event bus for notify when the server sends this error?

the idea is that each activity subscribes to listen the errors, and in case we get an HttpException we could communicate with the activity by using RxAndroid like Event Bus?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the solution for you. It will work under assumption that Dagger 2 will be implemented properly. The sooner you do it - the better for you.

Create some Singleton SampleDAO(google Android DAO pattern) class. This class will be responsible for performing API request. Inject this class inside the service or wherever you want, and perform API request through the stimulation of the performRequest Subject like this - sampleDao.performRequest().onNext(null);

```
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;

import javax.inject.Singleton;

import rx.Observable;
import rx.Observer;
import rx.android.schedulers.AndroidSchedulers;
import rx.functions.Func1;
import rx.schedulers.Schedulers;
import rx.subjects.PublishSubject;

@Singleton
public class SampleDao {

    @NonNull
    PublishSubject<Object> performRequest = PublishSubject.create();
    @NonNull
    Observable<SomeData> apiResponse;

    public SampleDao(final @NonNull ApiService apiService) {

        apiResponse = performRequest
                .switchMap(new Func1<Object, Observable<SomeData>>() {
                    @Override
                    public Observable<SomeData> call(Object o) {
                        return apiService.apiRequest()
                                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io());
                    }
                });
    }

    @NonNull
    public Observable<SomeData> getApiResponse() {
        return apiResponse;
    }

    @NonNull
    public Observer<Object> performRequest() {
        return performRequest;
    }
}
```

You need to create presenter as well. In this presenter pass SampleDao as a reference to constructor (Dagger 2 handle this).

```
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;

import rx.Observable;

public class SamplePresenter {

    @NonNull
    private final Observable<SomeData> someDataObservable;

    public SamplePresenter(SampleDao sampleDao) {

        someDataObservable = sampleDao.getApiResponse();
    }

    @NonNull
    public Observable<SomeData> getSomeDataObservable() {
        return someDataObservable;
    }
}
```

Inject presenter in the Activity/Fragment in which you would like to handle response or error.

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.trello.rxlifecycle.components.RxActivity;

import javax.inject.Inject;

import rx.Subscriber;


public class MainActivity extends RxActivity {

    @Inject
    SamplePresenter samplePresenter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        samplePresenter.getSomeDataObservable()
                .compose(this.<SomeData>bindToLifecycle())
                .subscribe(new Subscriber<SomeData>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted() {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable e) {
                        final ErrorHelper errorHelper = new ErrorHelper(getResources(), e);
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, errorHelper.getErrorMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNext(SomeData someData) {
                    }
                });
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what is the function of ".compose(this.<SomeData>bindToLifecycle())" ? how do you deal with the Activity's lifecycle?

Comment: It prevents from memory leaks. You can read something about it here github.com/trello/RxLifecycle. It also prevents from NPE on views when observable emits value after view is destroyed and you are trying to set some value inside subscribe action

Comment: where is the best place to add the "  .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())" ?? in the DAO or in the Activity ?